# ¿Que significa este Warning en Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy analizando unos datos con `pandas` y a la hora de escribir este código:

```
df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df.drop(columns='Date', inplace=True)
df
```

Me aparece este "Warning":

> UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to `dateutil`. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format.
> df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

En la impresión me puede mostrar la tabla y me hace el cambio de "Date" a "Fecha". Pero solo quería saber como solucionarlo para que no me salga "Warning" O ¿Esta bien dejarlo?
Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Porque no especificas el argumento format de to_datetime?: format="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S": df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"); Pagina recomendada [Función de Pandas to_datetime para convertir la columna del DataFrame en datetime](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python-pandas/how-to-convert-dataframe-column-to-datetime-in-pandas/#funci%C3%B3n-de-pandas-to_datetime-para-convertir-la-columna-del-dataframe-en-datetime)

Comment: Buen día, ¿Has intentado con `errors='ignore'` o especificando el formato como menciona @DanielBriceño?

Comment: hola @DanielBriceño si lo intente y me sale una key error

Comment: @HeytalePazguato no, no lo he intentado pondia ese ignore despues de df.Date'

Comment: Es un argumento de `to_datetime`... creo que hizo falta investigar un poco en la documentación jaja

Comment: Que contiene df.Date?.

Comment: Es una columna de mi dataframe y contiene esto(7/11/23)

Comment: Por eso te da error. Lo que yo te di pide hora minutos y segundo aparte.

Comment: @DanielBriceño Queria extraer los diferentes componentes de una fecha para generar nuevas variables

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta. Prueba con format="%m/%d/%Y" a ver que te sale:)

Comment: @DanielBriceño si, disculpa lo probe tambien con %m%d%Y y me da error.

Comment: @DanielBriceño este error me sale, AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147732/discussion-between-daniel-briceno-and-chinaskidev).

Comment: @chinaskidev, lo mejor sería que agregaras un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y algunas filas de tu `dataset` con lo que podamos reproducir tu problema.